# AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: child process misconfigured

Tags: node.js, process, child-process, assertion

I have a `test.js` file that takes in a child_process and checks for an environment variable **MY_ENV_VAR**, which is set in my `index.js` file exercise function. When I run `node test.js` the  test fail with an error saying AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: child process misconfigured. I have tried debugging but nothing has lead to any solid conclusions. I believe that the child process is not receiving the correct output.Below are the files needed for this exercise:

#### Additional Info

I have added additional commands to the spawn method, which are reflected below in the `index.js` file. This now causes another assertion error because the length of my environment variables is not equal to one specified by the **assertion.strictEqual** in the `child.js` file. the child process is receiving system environment variables instead of the environmental variable relative to this process. So if I can limit the scope of the environment variable then the program will work as intended.

#### index.js

```
'use strict'
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

function exercise (myEnvVar) {
  // TODO return a child process with
  // a single environment variable set 
  // named MY_ENV_VAR. The MY_ENV_VAR 
  // environment variable's value should 
  // be the value of the myEnvVar parameter 
  // passed to this exercise function
  process.env.MY_ENV_VAR = myEnvVar
  return spawn(process.execPath, 
['child.js', '-e','process.env',
 '-e', 'process.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)', '-e', 'process.exit(0)']);
}
module.exports = exercise
```

#### child.js

```
'use strict'
const assert = require('assert')
const clean = (env) => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(env).filter(([k]) => !/^(_.*|pwd|shlvl)/i.test(k))
)
const env = clean(process.env)

assert.strictEqual(env.MY_ENV_VAR, 'is set')
assert.strictEqual(
  Object.keys(env).length,
  1,
  'child process should have only one env var'
)
console.log('passed!')
```

#### test.js

```
'use strict'
const assert = require('assert')
const { equal } = assert.strict
const exercise = require('.')

let sp = null
try {
  sp = exercise('is set')
  assert(sp, 'exercise function should return a child process instance')
  if (Buffer.isBuffer(sp)) {
    equal(sp.toString().trim(), 'passed!', 'child process misconfigured')
    process.stdout.write(sp)
    return
  }
} catch (err) { 
  const { status} = err
  if (status == null) throw err
  equal(status, 0, 'exit code should be 0')
  return
}

if (!sp.on) {
  const { stdout, stderr } = sp
  if (stderr.length > 0) process.stderr.write(stderr)
  if (stdout.length > 0) process.stdout.write(stdout)
  equal(sp.status, 0, 'exit code should be 0')
  equal(stdout.toString().trim(), 'passed!', 'child process misconfigured')
  return
}

let out = ''
if (sp.stderr) sp.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)
if (sp.stdout) {
  sp.stdout.once('data', (data) => { out = data })
  sp.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
} else {
  // stdio may be misconfigured, or fork method may be used,
  // allow benefit of the doubt since in either case
  // exit code check will still fail:
  out = 'passed!'
}
const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
  equal(out.toString().trim(), 'passed!', 'child process misconfigured')
}, 1000)

sp.once('exit', (status) => {
  equal(status, 0, 'exit code should be 0')
  equal(out.toString().trim(), 'passed!', 'child process misconfigured')
  clearTimeout(timeout)
})
```

All help is welcome and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the function in `index.js` and the code executes as attended. The correct solution is below:

#### index.js

```
'use strict'
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

function exercise (myEnvVar) {
  // TODO return a child process with
  // a single environment variable set 
  // named MY_ENV_VAR. The MY_ENV_VAR 
  // environment variable's value should 
  // be the value of the myEnvVar parameter 
  // passed to this exercise function
  return spawn(process.execPath, ['child.js'], {
    env: {MY_ENV_VAR: myEnvVar}
  });
}
module.exports = exercise
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I am working on the same project as you. Note that we are not able to clean up the environment variables of the child process with the following code on **Windows** as of **Node.js version 16**. (It works fine on **Linux** though)

```
function exercise (myEnvVar) {
  // TODO return a child process with
  // a single environment variable set 
  // named MY_ENV_VAR. The MY_ENV_VAR 
  // environment variable's value should 
  // be the value of the myEnvVar parameter 
  // passed to this exercise function
  return spawn(process.execPath, ['child.js'], {
    env: {MY_ENV_VAR: myEnvVar}
  });
}
```